# When we pass multiple input for clip stitching it returns error aws elastic transcoder

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

When we pass the multiple input video for the clip stitching,
but it returns error Input must be an array of properties,Got numerically

*indexed array*

```
$result = $client - > createJob(array(
    'PipelineId' => '151111112277-cq5k40',
    'Input' => array(array('Key' => 'test.mp4'), array('Key' => 'abc.mp4')),

    'Output' => array(
        'Key' => $output_file,
        'PresetId' => '1351621234501-000001',
        'Composition' => array(
            array(
                'TimeSpan' => array(

                    'StartTime' => '00:00:00.000',
                    'Duration' => '00:01:00.000',
                )
            )

        ),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Docs suggest `'Input' => ...` is an array of properties, but `'Inputs' => ...` is an array of arrays of properties, with `Input` being used when there's only one file, or `Inputs` used with multiple files.

> `Input`
>
> Type: `JobInput` structure
>
> A section of the request body that provides information about the file that is being transcoded.
>
> `Inputs`
>
> Type: Array of `JobInput` structures
>
> A section of the request body that provides information about the files that are being transcoded.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-elastictranscoder-2012-09-25.html#createjob

Comment: $result = $client->createJob(array('PipelineId' => '1234567-cqw5k40',
    
   'Inputs' =>array(

    array('Key' => 'KingsCollegeDynamic20180228111415.mp4',
    'TimeSpan' => array('Duration' => '00:00:04.000','StartTime' => '00:00:00.000')
    ),
    array('Key' => 'SampleVideo.mp4',
    'TimeSpan' => array('Duration' => '00:00:04.000','StartTime' => '00:00:00.000')
    ),

    ),

    'Outputs' => array(array(
        'Key' => $output_file,
        'PresetId' => '1351621234001-000001'),),
    
    
));  still give error ,include either input or an inputs do not include both

Comment: anyone please help